# how to read yii create command object without foreachloop

Tags: php, yii

I use create command of Yii as

```
$sql = "select name from users where id = 2";

$EmployeeName=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

now i have to use foreachloop to get specific value like

```
foreach($EmployeeName as $value)
$name = $value['name'];
```

Can i bypass foreach loop like

```
$EmployeeName -> name; //To get value of specific field
```

Question is why i use `foreach` loop when i know i have single index array?
when i am using `print_r($EmployeeName)` its showing me sql command in object instead of data so i am confused how to debug object array

Comment: I think its because you are using query all. try $EmployeeName[0]->name

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `id` is your primary key, you should use [`queryScalar`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#query-detail) instead. This will return a single value and not an array.

```
$name=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax in Yii:

```
$user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => 2));
$name = $user->name;
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Single line solution

The simplest approach is find by primary key (PK).

Suppose `id` is PK in the `Users` model (Users model should be set thru [gii model generator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii)):

```
$name = Users::model()->findByPk(2)->name;
```